# Parallel numbering

Tags: numbering

In my script I want to have a structure as illustrated in the following example:

1 Section

1.1 Subsection

1.2 Subsection

1.A Exercise

1.B Exercise

1.3 Subsection

2 Section

2.1 Subsection

etc.

How can I realize this?

Comment: parallel as in *parallel universe*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the macros `\exercise` and `\maintext` to switch between your main text and exercise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{savesubsection}[section]\setcounter{savesubsection}{0}
\newcounter{saveexercise}[section]\setcounter{saveexercise}{0}

\def\exercise{\global\setcounter{savesubsection}{\value{subsection}}%
  \global\setcounter{subsection}{\thesaveexercise}%
  \global\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}}

\def\maintext{\global\setcounter{saveexercise}{\value{subsection}}%
  \global\setcounter{subsection}{\thesavesubsection}%
  \global\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}}


\begin{document}

\maintext

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsection{Subsection}

\exercise


\subsection{Exercise}

\subsection{Exercise}

\maintext

\subsection{Subsection}

\exercise

\subsection{Exercise}

\section{Section}
\maintext

\subsection{Subsection}

\exercise

\subsection{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Here I have assumed that you will have only one set of exercise per section. If you want more than one group of exercise per section, please let me know. I will arrange saving your previous exercise subsection to be resumed later.

**EDIT**

I have updated the above code to allow switching between main text and exercise as many times as you  like. The code is not yet thoroughly tested.

---

I understand that we can add further flags to test which *environment* we are currently in, e.g. if the user puts another `\exercise` while still inside exercise. But I am ignoring such mistakes.

Comment: Yes exactly. Now the numbering of exercises is reset after each \exercise switch. It would be great if I can put in more than one exercise section.

Comment: @A.S. Please give me a few minutes, let me try

Comment: @A.S. Updated the code. But please be informed that I am still testing it.

Comment: This looks fine to me. Really great thanks !

Comment: Another question on this: Is it possible to produce a numerering like Exercise A*, Exercise B*, Exercise C , Exercise D, Exercise E*. So I want to add a * to the Index if needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{exercise}[section]
\renewcommand{\theexercise}{\thesection.\@Alph\c@exercise}
\if@twoside
  \g@addto@macro{\ps@headings}{%
    \def\exercisemark##1{%
      \markright{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
          \theexercise\quad
        \fi
        ##1}}
  }
\fi
\g@addto@macro{\ps@myheadings}{\let\exercisemark\@gobble}
\newcommand{\exercisemark}[1]{}
\newcommand{\exercise}{\@startsection{exercise}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\exercise{Exercise}
\exercise{Exercise}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

*(Edited according to @egreg's comment.)*

Comment: If I type \exercise{Exercise} the output is  
"1.A Exercise  
  Exercise  "
Is it possible that the text in brackets only occurs once after the numbering ?

Comment: This is truly a problem. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Great thanks so far. Except this, its really great.

Comment: You have to add `\newcommand\exercisemark[1]{}`

Comment: It's useless to have `\def\exercisemark` in `\ps@heading` unless you really want to have exercises in the header.

Comment: My initial idea was to keep this feature.